# Location of couch.ini file in couchdb1.6

Tags: couchdb

Hi Some one please help me to find couch.ini file for my couchdb [v1.6].
when i do `couchdb -c` i am able to see only `default.ini` and `local.ini`.
Is there a command to find the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [this link](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Example%20usages%20of%20DbUpdateNotification) we read:

> (0.8) Add the following line to the couch.ini file
>
> DbUpdateNotificationProcess=/PATH/TO/view_updater.rb
>
> (0.9+) Add the following section to the local.ini file:
>
> [update_notification]
> view_updater=/PATH/TO/view_updater.rb

Your version is `1.6` which is `0.9+`, therefore you need to add  the following line to **local.ini**:

```
[update_notification]
view_updater=/PATH/TO/view_updater.rb
```

Comment: So where is couch.ini file.

Comment: I was going through the following document https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/RegeneratingViewsOnUpdate?action=show, there i am asked to add a parameter in couch.ini file